# How can I make udev accept mass storage and reject everything else?

Tags: usb, udev, usb-drive

I'm trying to write a udev rule to allow USB mass storage devices but reject anything else (keyboard, mouse, etc). I found this online:

```
ACTION!="add", GOTO="deauthorize_end"
SUBSYSTEM!="usb", GOTO="deauthorize_end"
TEST!="authorized", GOTO="deauthorize_end"

## make hubs deauthorize all devices by default
TEST=="authorized_default", ATTR{authorized_default}="0", GOTO="deauthorize_end"

## CHECK FOR USB MASS STORAGE HERE
SOMETHING=="something", ENV{valid}="1"


## authorize matched devices, warn about the rest
ENV{valid}=="1", ENV{valid}="", ATTR{authorized}="1", GOTO="deauthorize_end"
RUN+="/usr/local/bin/usb-unauth $devpath"
LABEL="deauthorize_end"
```

I have this saved in /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-unauth.rule - my problem is the CHECK FOR USB MASS STORAGE bit, I can't work out what to put there. The rule is working fine because I can put other things in there like vendor/product IDs and they work fine.

I've tried SUBSYSTEM=="block", SUBSYSTEMS=="block" and all sorts of other keys found using `udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/myDevNode)` but nothing seems to make it accept the drive.

What am I doing wrong? What can I match on to catch *all* mass storage devices? It needs to be all, not just a specific one.

**Edit**: Looking at the udev log it seems like my rule is running too soon:

```
set children_max to 16
validate module index
Check if link configuration needs reloading.
seq 2693 queued, 'add' 'usb'
seq 2693 forked new worker [26127]
seq 2693 running
no db file to read /run/udev/data/c189:224: No such file or directory
device 0xb77b68e0 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1'
device 0xb77b6c90 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2'
device 0xb77b7040 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0'
device 0xb77b72c8 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00'
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:9
IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:9
MODE 0664 /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:41
ATTR '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/authorized' writing '1' /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-deauth.rules:21
```

Surely my rule, starting with 99-... should not be run **third**? I think I need it to run later.

*Another edit*: So I think the problem is that as soon as we get past `SUBSYSTEM!="usb", GOTO="deauthorize_end"` (i.e., SUBSYSTEM=="usb") the rest of this rule is evaluated, and I can see from udevadm that at that point the usb subsystem is just "USB" to get "usb-storage" it needs to go one level up. Is there any way to do that from the rule?

Comment: Try adding another key after `SUBSYSTEM=="block",`  e.g. `ENV{ID_USB_DRIVER}=="usb-storage"` and/or `ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb"`...